# Get select fields from find method from mysql Database in Moleculer Framework

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, moleculer

Can you please suggest how to get select fields from find method ?

e.g

```
let params = {
        limit,
        offset,
        query: request
                };
    this.adapter.find(params)
```

Here, this will return all fields but instead of this I need only account_id from the resultset. I've already tried with fields inside params as well as settings{ fields: ["accout_id", "username"]} but doesn't work.

e.g

```
fields: ["account_id"]
```

Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: The field name for that is `attributes` so your object would need to have the same property name. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#attributes

Comment: So are you suggested by this ways ?
 let params = {
    limit,
    offset,
    query: request,
    fields: ['account_id'] //OR attributes: ['account_id']
    };

this.adapter.find(params);

I've already tried with this ways but doesn't work.

Comment: I am having the same issue now, can you provide how you declared your `model` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... I got the solution. I've used 'this.model' intead of 'this.adapter' like following way.

```
let params = {
                limit,
                offset,
                query: request
            };   

 this.model.find({
                    attributes: ['account_id'],
                    where : first_name : {
                            $like: '%Adam%'
                                }
                    })
```